# How long it takes to publish contract in test network?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Rinkebery test network. 
I published test contract an hour ago, but still 0 of 12 confirmations. Is it normal for test network, or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Screnshot from Etherium client]

Answer (score 0):

My contract on the testnet got deployed within 5 minutes with average+ transfer fees.

IMO, it depends mainly on  how much transaction fees you are offering to miners for the process. If you keep the fees almost 0 then your contract will not likely be mined by most of the miners.

I've sent an ether on one of my accounts today itself with 0 transfer fees. Its been 3 hours and I haven't got a single confirmation.

Hope this helps you!